# Scid PGN analysis using Stockfish

Tags: pgn, scid

Scid outputs this analysis of a PGN file using the Stockfish engine:

[image]

What does the `D` mean? And where (e.g. a web page) is this actually explained?

Comment: Are you using SCID?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Stockfish. It's the GUI that did that.

Comment: question updated

Comment: I think it means `diagram`?

Comment: I've added an answer to your question. In addition maybe it's useful for you to know about another special comment: those with the format `****D{d} {n}->{m}`. These are tactical problems detected by Scid, where `{d}` is the dificulty of the problem, and `{n}` and `{m}` the evaluation of the position before and after the last move.

When such a problem is found the game is tagged as "Tactical" (`T`) and a database with tactical games can be used with Scid's tactical training feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special mark meaning `diagram`. When you export the game into a PDF/LaTeX file positions after moves marked with `D` are rendered in the document.

The only documentation I've found is https://sourceforge.net/p/scid/wiki/HowToExportGames/. Scid vs PC documentation maybe is clearer http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Export.htm. But documentation is actually poor, I discovered this feature just testing the `Export to LaTeX` feature.